# Does the default Reactjs application use node.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

This may be a dumb question, but is the default react app (created using `npm create-react-app my-app`) using node.js? I am confused because in my web development class at university, I had to download node.js to create react applications. However, I didn't have to do anything like creating a server or initiating a node.js file, which is described in w3school's node.js tutorial. Because of this, I found out that I don't even really know what node is used for, besides downloading packages like redux and whatnot.

Comment: This is off topic for Stack Overflow so it'll probably be closed. Node essentially lets you run Javascript outside a browser. As Javascript is a programming language, Node can be used for all sorts of things, installing packages, making servers, web scraping, etc.. In the case of CRA, while you're developing there's a lot going on behind the scenes, Node is transpiling the files you write, and watching the files for changes so it can refresh the browser, and so on.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize this was off topic so I screenshotted all the replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`create-react-app` uses node.js for all of its dev tooling. Likewise, a lot of the tools you'll use in the React ecosystem (like webpack, prettier, npm), all run on top of node.js as well).

You'll most probably build your react app to a static file, in which case the production output will not require node.js, it will be html and javascript assets that can be served directly to a client.

Hope that helps! Let me know if you have other specific questions

Comment: Thank you! This explains it really well and I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help! Could you accept this as answer if it's helpful? 

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is used for server-side while React.js is for the front-end part. So, no, you don't need Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Under development mode, yes. Create react app runs NodeJs with Webpack Dev Server to allow you get feedback when modifing files, start or stop the server.